# Angular 2 navbar component not "active" when router outlet displays different component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My goal is to check the width on window.onresize for my navbar component to change the logo for mobile vs. PC. I have the window resize functionality working in another component so I know it works. My app component template looks like this:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <navigation></navigation>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
```

The problem is once the router "routes" to another component, the window.onresize functionality stops happening in the navigation component. This is the window.onresize functionality:

```
window.onresize = (e) =>
                {
                    _ngZone.run(() => {
                        this.checkWidth();
                    });
                };
```

When I comment out the router outlet from the app component template (so it's just the nav bar), Then the resizing functionality works fine in the navbar component. Any idea how to keep it working in the navbar when the router outlet routes to another component?

Comment: where are you calling this function?

Comment: @Fals in the constructor. I know I can use media queries with display:none, but I wanted to use *ngIf.

Comment: You should call anything that interacts with DOM at ngAfterViewInit